# Liveness Probes Control With Sctp

Tags: kubernetes, sctp, livenessprobe

Kubernetes use tcp, http and command for liveness probes but i want to use sctp. How can i use **sctp with liveness probes** for control my page?

Answer (score 0):

For not supported protocols you can use the `exec` probe. You just have to provide a shell script, that can check if the application is running. The script has to exit with code 0 to be considered successful.

```yaml
...
          livenessProbe: 
            exec:
              command:
                - /scripts/check-sctp-up.sh
...
```